# Color Visible in Large Quantities of Ethanol

Tags: water, color

I am currently writing a sci-fi novel and have come upon a rather ponderous question that I have thus been incapable of discerning an answer for. **If a planet were to have oceans composed not of water, but rather of ethanol or a similar alcohol, what would they look like from space, assuming an atmosphere similar to earth's?** What I've found thus far implies that ethanol and other pure alcohols are simply clear, however, in small quantities (such as in a glass), water also has an apparently clear color. Knowing that water, in larger quantities, absorbs red, yellow, and green light more readily than blue, making it appear blue, I was assuming that other liquids might perform similarly, making large quantities of them a far different color than in isolated quantities.

Comment: If somebody has access to this database, this paper may have the info you are looking for:
http://pubs.rsc.org/en/Content/ArticleLanding/1968/TF/tf9686402081#!divAbstract